# Is my pyvenv.cfg messed up between Homebrew and MacOS based python executable?

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

Using PyCharm, I started a new project and got the following `pyvenv.cfg`:

```
home = /usr/local/bin
implementation = CPython
version_info = 3.12.0.final.0
virtualenv = 20.24.5
include-system-site-packages = false
base-prefix = /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12
base-exec-prefix = /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12
base-executable = /usr/local/bin/python3.12
```

As one can see, there are two different Python installations mentioned: the one that gets shipped by MacOS, and my custom Python installation brought by Homebrew.

What is the best advice to deal with that?